# take the average of each index in a double[] hash map and assign it to an output double[]

Tags: java, hashmap, average

I want to implement the averaged perceptron algorithm, in accordance with [**this description**](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_8/ciml-v0_8-ch03.pdf) (page 48, complete with psuedocode).

I think I'm pretty close, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out the last step wherein I need to compute the average of the weights calculated during every iteration for each particular index, and then assign that value to a final array of weights. How would I implement that?

The structure of the hashmap is `int` which is the number of iterations, and then an array of `double[]` with the weights for that iteration. so i guess the output would be something like

```
For all the hashmap keys
    for the length of the hashmap value at this key index
        ...something
```

So if each iteration the first weight was `2`, `4`, ,`3`, I want to assign the weight of `3` to the final `double[]` array for that index, and so on for all the instances.

Below is the pertinent code. The full code is [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron) in case you'd like to check it out.

```
   //store weights to be averaged. 
   Map<Integer,double[]> cached_weights = new HashMap<Integer,double[]>();


   final int globoDictSize = globoDict.size(); // number of features

   // weights total 32 (31 for input variables and one for bias)
   double[] weights = new double[globoDictSize + 1];
   for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
   {
       //weights[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 10000;
       //weights[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
       weights[i] = 0.0;
   }


   int inputSize = trainingPerceptronInput.size();
   double[] outputs = new double[inputSize];
   final double[][] a = Prcptrn_InitOutpt.initializeOutput(trainingPerceptronInput, globoDictSize, outputs, LABEL);


   double globalError;
   int iteration = 0;
   do 
   {
       iteration++;
       globalError = 0;
       // loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
       for (int p = 0; p < inputSize; p++) 
       {
           // calculate predicted class
           double output = Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput(THETA, weights, a, p);
           // difference between predicted and actual class values
           //always either zero or one
           double localError = outputs[p] - output;

           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
           {
               weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a[i][p];
           }
           weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError;

           // summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
           globalError += localError * localError;
       }
```

here's the part I was mentioning above

```
       //calc averages
       for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
       {
            int key = entry.getKey();
            double[] value = entry.getValue();
            // ...
        }

       /* Root Mean Squared Error */
       //System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt(globalError / inputSize));
   } 
   while (globalError != 0 && iteration <= MAX_ITER);


   //calc averages
   Iterator it = cached_weights.entrySet().iterator();
   while( it.hasNext() ) 
   {
       Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

       it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this would work:

```
   //calc averages
   for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
   {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        double[] value = entry.getValue();
        AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] +=  value[ key - 1 ]; 
    }
```

But then, must make some term for dividing by the # of iterations at the end I guess

like if key is at the end of the key, there's no more bigger iterations, if that is the case, then divide by it, something like that.

maybe this?

```
   //calc averages
   for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
   {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        double[] value = entry.getValue();
        AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] +=  value[ key - 1 ]; 

        if (key == iteration) 
        {
            AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] /= key;
        }
    }
```