# calculate the average value across indicies of a hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

I tried writing this code to test out my idea on how to calculate the average value across like indices of a hash map.
i.e. for each array contained within the hashmap if the first value for the first array was `2`, and the first value for the second array was  `4` , and the first value for the third array was `3`, I want to assign the value of (4+3+2/3)= `3` to the final double[] array for the first index, and so on for all the indices 2 through n.

```
    int Size = 3;

    double[] AVERAGED_WEIGHTS = new double[Size];

    //store weights to be averaged. 
    Map<Integer,double[]> cached_weights = new HashMap<Integer,double[]>();

    double[] weights = new double[Size];

   int iteration = 0;
   do 
   {
       weights[iteration] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 10000;

       iteration++;

       //store weights for averaging
       cached_weights.put( iteration , weights );  
    } 
    while (iteration < Size);

    //calc averages
    for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
    {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        double[] value = entry.getValue();
        AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] +=  value[ key - 1 ]; 

        if (key == iteration) 
        {
            AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] /= key;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
    {
       weights[i] = AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[i];
    }
```

This mimics the structure of the original program wherein the weights are populated through a do while loop. This code is broken though and does not sucessfully perform the operation described above. I've been searching online and trying different ways to fix it but I've not been able to solve it. Perhaps someone can spot my faulty logic.

Comment: your code has so many flaws. `AVERAGED_WEIGHTS[ key - 1 ] +=  value[ key - 1 ]; ` as well as in condition you are deviding with key but not storing anywhere. and why you used last loop??

Comment: dig [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688007/take-the-average-of-each-index-in-a-double-hash-map-and-assign-it-to-an-output) it's more complete description of what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Prashant do you agree that the answer by Daniel is correct?

Comment: you want to find average of all the first element of all array??

Comment: yeah and save that to the first element in a new array, and then the same for the second, same for the third, so on like that, you know?

Comment: then below posted answer will work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but you are not computing the average because for each array in your map, you are not taking into account all its positions. You are using the key and that makes absolutely no sense. Anyways, your code is very confusing. What you need to do is simply one loop inside the other. One going through the arrays and another going through the elements of each array. A way to compute the average is the following (in a didactic way):

```
//compute averages
double[] sums = new double[size];
double[] averages = new double[size];

for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cachedWeights.entrySet()) {
    double[] value = entry.getValue();
    for(int pos=0; pos < Math.min(size, value.length); pos++){
        sums[pos] +=  value[pos]; 
    }
}
for(int pos=0; pos < size; pos++){
    averages[pos] = sums[pos] / cachedWeights.size(); 
}
```

Comment: Would that be applicable to [this application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688007/take-the-average-of-each-index-in-a-double-hash-map-and-assign-it-to-an-output)?

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I think base on his scenario, finally, we should divide by map keySet.size().

Comment: why divide by keySet.size()?

Comment: I'm first summing all the elements in each position. Like 4+3+2 in your example. Then, at the end, you have to divide by the number of arrays that you summed (3 in your example)

Comment: i think this is the right solution for your problem. initially i got confused with your code.

Comment: And yes, if you are trying to implement a perceptron algorithm, that's the way to go (assuming that each array is the weight vector of your classifier at each step). By the way, a map is not the best data structure for the perceptron algorithm. A list of arrays would be a better choice.

Comment: sorry, no need to divide by keySet.size(), just do as Daniel do. keySet.size() is equal to your map size, which is how many entry you have in your map

Comment: @DanielX2010 yeah! perceptron exactly. why do you say list of arrays is better?

Comment: Because the weights are updated sequentially, and you sequentially update them. a map is completely unnecessary in this case. Your map keys here are 1, 2, 3, 4... You should use a map when your keys assume values that are not sequential and/or "scattered".